# Combinatorics Involving Seating People in a Line

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways can 3 people be seated in a 10 chair line, such that none of the people are sitting next to each other? Also how can any such problem for x people and y chairs, be solved?

I was unsure how to come up with a formula for a Choose b, regarding this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine that there are $7$ empty chairs in a row like this:
$$\times\quad\times\quad\times\quad\times\quad\times\quad\times\quad\times$$
Now the organizer goes to another room to get $3$ more chairs,  the ones our $3$ people will actually sit on. When she returns, she chooses $3$ of the $8$ "gaps" between the existing chairs to slide the new chairs into. This includes the $2$ "endgaps."

The choosing can be done in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways. Now if we are to take account of who sits where, we need to multiply by $3!$.

This simplifies to $\frac{8!}{5!}$.

The problem for $x$ people and $y$ chairs is solved in the same way. If $x\gt y-x+1$, there are no ways to do the job.

Comment: Great answer with simple explanation. Upvoted.

Comment: I guess here you're assuming people are distinct (which they should be), but chairs are identical. If chairs had numbers, then only the numbers of ways the chairs could be relabeled should be multiplied: 10!

Comment: Chairs are automatically all distinguishable, since each has a definite relative position.   If the problem said there are $10$  people who will sit, $3$ specified ones of whom must be separated, we would multiply our $\frac{8!}{3!}$ by $7!$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How would we do $n$ chairs with $m$ people who have to have at least two chairs between them? At least $k$ chairs between them?

Comment: @EricAuld:  Interesting question< I will think about it.  Presumably a Stars and Bars variant.

Comment: I posted it as a separate question here. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440607/counting-chair-arrangements-with-multiple-gaps

Comment: It is fairly late in the evening. If it is not answered by tomorrow, I will look at it.