# Possible number of email addresses given 39 characters

Tags: combinatorics

I've been working on this problem which asks me the number of possible 8 character email addresses (only the local part, before @) that can be made up using A-Z ( or a-z both mean the same), 0-9 and ".","-","_" provided that "." cant appear at the beginning or at the end. It also cannot appear consecutively.

I'm struggling with this as combinatorics is not my strong suit. So far i'm leaning towards:

38*39*39*39*39*39*39*38 - 6!

Am i on the right path? Could some explain the approach to be taken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $38^8$ choices with no periods. Now we count the choices with periods.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438753/combinatorics-involving-seating-people-in-a-line) question shows that there are $\binom{6-k+1}{k}$ ways to choose $k$ spots for periods to go in the middle six spots, such that no two periods are adjacent (if $k \leq 3$. If $k>3$ there are no ways). So we need to sum on the possible numbers of periods, times the number of options for the other characters once we've fixed the periods. This gives us final answer

$$38^8 + \binom{6-1+1}{1}\cdot 38^7 + \binom{6-2+1}{2}\cdot 38^6 +  \binom{6 - 3 +1}{3}\cdot 38^5$$

There may be a more elegant way to do the counting. I'm interested if anyone has one!